# Run webapp generated with JHipster : Mapper could not be found

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, jhipster, mapstruct

When I run my webapp with Eclipse IDE (Right click + run as Java application)

I have the following error :

```
2018-08-14 15:58:17.381  WARN 7324 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actionServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\dfsdfdsfdsfsfsfsf\target\classes\com\showyou\service\impl\ActionServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.showyou.service.mapper.ActionMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Does anybody has an idea ? I followed all the required steps : https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-eclipse/

Comment: Mapper implementations get generated by maven or gradle at build time by MapStruct annotation processor. If you are unable to configure Eclipse to run MapStruct annotation processor, just run `mvn compile`

Comment: In Intellij IDEA you'd have to tick File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Enable annotation processing to enable mapper generation. For Eclipse maybe [JHipster IDE plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jhipster-ide) would work?